# How to automatically print a form when a new item is posted to a list in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint

How to automatically print a form when a new item is posted to a list in SharePoint?

I created a list in SP, with customized Entry and Edit forms and a workflow that connects them. Every time a new item is posted the Entry form needs to be used, but when I click submit I need the workflow not only to post the item to the list, but also generate a 'Print form' that can either saved or printed.

Comment: Please edit your question with more detail as mentioned by Argalatyr!

Comment: I would like to consider both options. But will choose which ever is easier to apply (I am new to SharePoint, but learn quickly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the event, adding an item triggers an [SPItemEventReceiver.ItemAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadded.aspx). You would call your printing code from within this event, and deploy the functionality through a [Feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453149.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

To give a really specific answer, you'll need to explain a bit more - where should the printing occur?  On the machine from which the list was modified, or some central printing location?

More generally, Sharepoint can trigger a variety of events.  Ishai Sagi's blog has [a user-triggered solution](http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2007/01/how-to-add-print-list-option-to-list.html) that may give you some ideas.  You could use [a Javascript event as explained here](http://metahat.blogspot.com/2008/01/printing-sharepoint-web-part.html).  You could even send a specially-formatted email to a computer with Outlook running, with a rule that triggers a print.

Comment: I would like to consider both options. But will choose which ever is easier to apply (I am new to SharePoint, but learn quickly).